# Inverse of an invertible upper triangular matrix is upper triangular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

Let $A$ be a ring and $B:=(\lambda_{ij})_{ij}$ an upper triangular $n\times n$ matrix over $A$ whose diagonal elements are invertible. I want to show that $B^{-1}$ exists and is upper triangular.

Let $(e_i)_i$ be the canonical basis of $A^{\oplus n}_d$. Since the diagonal elements of $B$ are invertible, there exists $u\in\mathbb{GL}(A^{\oplus n}_d)$ such that $u(e_i)=\sum_{j=1}^ne_j\lambda_{ji}$. This shows that $B^{-1}=M(u^{-1})=\left(\langle e^*_k,u^{-1}(e_i)\rangle\right)_{ki}$.

Now, we have to finish by showing that $B^{-1}$ is in fact upper triangular: i.e. that for $i<k$ we have $\langle e^*_k,u^{-1}(e_i)\rangle=0$; this means that the $k$-th component of $u^{-1}(e_i)$ w.r.t. the basis $(e_i)_i$ is equal to zero.

Take $i<k$ in the interval $[1,n]$. Then $u^{-1}(e_i)=\sum_{l=1}^ne_la_l$ and
$$e_i=\sum_{l=1}^n\sum_{j=1}^ne_j\lambda_{jl}a_l=\sum_{j=1}^ne_j\left(\sum_{l=1}^n\lambda_{jl}a_l\right).$$
This implies that $\sum_{l=1}^n\lambda_{kl}a_l=0$. I am having difficulty showing that $a_k=0$. Any suggestions?

Comment: Induction.  Note that $Ae_1\oplus\dots\oplus Ae_k$ is $B$-invariant so take quotient.

Comment: induction worked, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't a simple induction argument work? We know that $e_{n} = a_{nn}^{-1} u_n$ and now $e_{n-1} = u_{n-1} - a_{n-1, n} e_n = u_{n-1} - a_{n-1, n} a_{n, n}^{-1} u_n,$ and so on.

Answer (score 2):

As $A=(a_{ij})\in\mathbb C^{n\times n}$ is invertible upper triangular, it can be written as $A=DB$, where $D=\mathrm{diag}(a_{11},\ldots,a_{nn})$ and $B=I+S$, where $I$ is the identity matrix and $S=(s_{ij})$ is *strictly* upper triangular, i.e., $s_{ij}=0$, whenever $i\ge j$.

But $S^k=0$, for $k\ge n$ and it is not hard to show that
$$
(I+S)^{-1}=I-S+S^2+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}S^{n-1}.
$$
Clearly, $(I+S)^{-1}$ is also upper triangular. Finally,
$$
A^{-1}=\big(D(I+S)\big)^{-1}=(I+S)^{-1}D^{-1}.
$$
Again upper triangular.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the result

$\begin{bmatrix}
C & X \\
0\cdots 0 & d \\
\end{bmatrix}^{-1} = $

$\begin{bmatrix}
C^{-1} & Y \\
0\cdots 0 & d^{-1} \\
\end{bmatrix}$

where $Y=-d^{-1}C^{-1} X.$

Comment: Even easier: By Cayley-Hamilton, $A^{-1}$ is a polynomial in $A.$